# Как проверить в javascript содержит ли текст введенный в prompt весь алфавит?

Tags: javascript

Как проверить в javascript содержит ли текст введенный в `prompt` все буквы русского алфавита и дать знать об этом при помощи `alert`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
alert(
  Object.keys(
    [...prompt("Введите", "Съешь ещё этих мягких французских булок, да выпей же чаю")]
    .reduce((r,ch) => (/[а-яё]/i.test(ch)&&(r[ch.toLowerCase()]=1),r), {})
  ).length === 33
)
```